# Vagrant accessing domain from another guest machine

Tags: vagrant

Now, i have 2 vm machine

First vm running api server.
Second vm acting like client that perform request to the api endpoint.

The api server name is http://api.dev
The client server name is http://client.dev

Here is vagrant file for the api server:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "lemp.dev"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www/html"  
end
```

Here is vagrant file for the client:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "lemp.dev"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.11"
  config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www/html"

end
```

Here is host file on my host machine:

```
192.168.10.11           client.dev
192.168.10.10           api.dev
```

I can access the http://api.dev from my host machine.

Problem is, i cant access the http://api.dev from my client machine.When i run `curl api.dev` i got 404 page

What i want is to be able to access to the http://api.dev from another vm instance( the second vm ).

Comment: did you update your host file on the client.dev vm ? not only the host machine

Comment: @FrédéricHenri im aware of that..if i update the host file on client.dev i can acces the domain..but i wonder is the a better way to do this?

Comment: you can look at the [vagrant hostmanager](https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager) plugin, the plugin can manage your host hosts file but also the hosts file from the guest.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri thx,i will take a look into it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to update the `hosts` file on the Guests (`192.168.10.11` and `192.168.10.10`) with the same thing you put on your Host, or you could just use the IPs and not have to worry about doing that.

Comment: is there a better way to do this? im aware if i add 192.168.10.10 to client.dev /etc/hosts i can access the domain..i just wonder is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No... the client.dev box has no way of knowing you want it to translate `api.dev` (locally) into an IP. Without modifying the `hosts` file it would ask your closest DNS (OS, ISP, etc .) to translate the FQDN into an IP, but since there is no record anywhere of what `api.dev` means nobody can translate it. This is why you have to explicitly define it in the `hosts` file. **Or just use the IPs**.

Comment: Or as Frédéric Henri points out in the comments of your question, you can use the `vagrant-hostmanager` plugin to try and automate this process. In my experience it has caused more issues than it solved, which is why I am not keen to recommend it.